# How to apply filter to a cell renderer in ag grid

Tags: angular, filter, render, ag-grid

I have an ag grid in my application

I am not able to get any filtered values applied on these columns.
How do we apply valueFormatter and filter params in this scenario?

In the below column, I am getting 0,1 as input and rendering them to strings using the cellrenderer option in ag-grid. as shown here in  [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/)

I have the below in my search input box

```
        //search box
       <mat-input-container>
        <input matInput placeholder="Quick Search" style="width: 250px" 
       (keyup)="onQuickFilterChanged($event)">
        </mat-input-container>
```

```
     // column definition in ag-grid
     {
    headerName: 'Header',
    field: 'isheader',
    width: 100,
    filter: 'string',
    cellRenderer: function (params: any) {
      if (params.value === 1) {
        return 'Yes';
      } if (params.value === 0) {
        return 'No';
      } 
      return params.value;
    },
    colId:'isPdm',
     },
```

Comment: Please expand what do you need and what problem you are facing. if possible put the code in plunker, that way you will get response faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter can be applied by adding another definition getQuickFilterText on the column as explained [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-quick/)

```
             getQuickFilterText:  function (params: any) {
      if (params.value === 1) {
        return 'Yes';
      } if (params.value === 0) {
        return 'No';
      } 
      return params.value;

    },
```