# Is there way to customise ag grid child count?

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

I m working with ag grid react, I have done row group. Now Parent row showing child row counts with numeric values. Is there any function to customise row count style.
And I  want to calculate rows count based on children rows cell values.

I'm new  working with ag grid. Can anyone have solution about my issue.

[image: current functionality working]

[image: we want functionality same as screenshot with second image]

Comment: Are you asking about group row count number ?

Comment: I'm asking about to customise number of rows count for row group. Child row counts is displaying  with parent rows. Means parent rows having N number of rows. That count I have to customise. Based on child cell values

Comment: Can you create an example to explain, ideally ag grid count the child rows only in the group count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I think this is exactly what you are looking for**

https://www.ag-grid.com/examples/grouping-group-rows/full-width-groups-rendering/modules/reactFunctional/index.html

Basically you are going to suppress group count and use a custom renderer

index.js

```
import GroupRowInnerRenderer from './groupRowInnerRenderer.jsx'
// ...

const GridExample = () => {
  const groupRowRendererParams = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      innerRenderer: GroupRowInnerRenderer,
      suppressCount: true,
    }
  }, [])

  // ...

  return (
    <AgGridReact
      rowData={rowData}
      columnDefs={columnDefs}
      defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
      columnTypes={columnTypes}
      groupDisplayType={'groupRows'}
      groupRowRendererParams={groupRowRendererParams}
      onGridReady={onGridReady}
    />
  )
}
```

and define your GroupRowInnerRenderer

groupRowInnerRenderer.jsx

```
export default (props) => {
  // customize it according to your needs
}
```

*You can read more here* https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grouping-group-rows/#configuring-group-cell-renderer

**UPDATE**

Alright, I have not much time but I know how to accomplish what you want

Working Plunker: https://plnkr.co/plunk/PzN5J6FJ5tCj4SAP

Do your calculation in the inner renderer component and set leafChildren. You need to put your own calculation logic here, the rest is easy.

You're going to dig leafChildren. Each children of every country in it has a data prop. This is what you are looking for.

[image]

**FINAL UPDATE**

To move expand icon, you need to follow something different: *cellRenderer*

cellRenderer.jsx

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default (props) => {
  const { node, value } = props
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(node.expanded)

  useEffect(() => {
    const expandListener = (event) => setExpanded(event.node.expanded)

    node.addEventListener('expandedChanged', expandListener)

    return () => {
      node.removeEventListener('expandedChanged', expandListener)
    }
  }, [])

  const onClick = useCallback(() => node.setExpanded(!node.expanded), [node])
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {node.group ? (
        <div
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            right: 10,
          }}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              cursor: 'pointer',
              transform: expanded ? 'rotate(90deg)' : 'rotate(0deg)',
              display: 'inline-block',
            }}
            onClick={onClick}
          >
            &rarr;
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        value
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
};
```

Now use it on your last column: Sport

```
{ field: 'sport', cellRenderer: CellRenderer },
```

Do not forget to remove the original expand icon returning nothing inside cellRendererSelector param of autoGroupColumnDef

```
const autoGroupColumnDef = useMemo(() => {
  return {
    headerName: 'Country',
    minWidth: 300,
    cellRendererSelector: (params) => {
      return
    },
  }
}, [])
```

[image: Result]

Here's the updated Plunker

https://plnkr.co/plunk/g6vz7zg5aWlgENqS

Comment: Please check my updated question I have added 2 screenshot. First screenshot with current functionality which is working. Second image functionality which we want

Comment: Please be more clear, your edited question cannot be understood

Comment: My question is we have row true for first column like country. In my first screenshot  country name is Zimbabwe(2).  Showing 2 count. Because it is having 2 children rows.  It is current functionality. But I need to customise it  like that 2 will be calculate based on there children   cell values which I have highlighted in second screenshot 2004 if  any children having 2004 then it should not include in child count row. In our row cell value if found 2004 then our row count will be  Zimbabwe(1).  Second thing is we need to display count number look like 1 Zimbabwe not Zimbabwe(1).

Comment: Which one is your updated answers please let me know

Comment: Yes it is working, now I'll check how to calculate data based on children rows cell values thanks @Ahmet Firat keler . I have one question related to expand collapse arrow icon I want display it right side just like below of last column how to do it

Comment: I have checked innerRenderer is working fine. But for cellrenderer I have checked for last column and return static text for cellrenderer so  it is showing text for all last column in front of children rows it is not displaying text for parent rows. @Ahmet Firat keler

Comment: I'll check it out

Comment: Of course, it is not going to show a text for parent rows because they are group rows. You can show group column values, total counts or averages in a parent row.

Comment: I'm able to display children rows count as per your shared innerenderer. But for icon cellrenderer is not working properly. It is working in your demo link. But as we I have implemented so it is showing icon in children rows not for parent row. Can you please give me suggestions for cellrenderer so that I can display it for parent row

Comment: Using innerRenderer I'm able to calculate children rows count based on cell values. I have also used quick filter so when search text from quick filter count is not working properly because it is not matched condition based on our cell values. Please look into this.

Comment: Please check cellRenderer.jsx file. We have a condition there, we only show the icon if the node is a group row. It is probably opposite in your code.

Comment: For your quick filter, you should apply getQuickFilterText for your column in which we used cellRenderer option. This is going to define how your quick filter is going to work for that particular column. Take a look at https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-quick/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49524702/how-to-apply-filter-to-a-cell-renderer-in-ag-grid

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the group header count by using

> cellRendererParams

There are multiple options available for cellRendererParams, If you intend to change the design then use `innerRenderer` in `cellRendererParams`

Adding the url link and example

Ag grid doc: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/group-cell-renderer

DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/WXykbAkY5iOK1FDp?open=index.jsx

-Help :)

Comment: Please check my updated question I have added 2 screenshot. First screenshot with current functionality which is working. Second image functionality which we want

Comment: How to write jest test cases for.   const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(node.expanded)

  useEffect(() => {
    const expandListener = (event) => setExpanded(event.node.expanded)

    node.addEventListener('expandedChanged', expandListener)

    return () => {
      node.removeEventListener('expandedChanged', expandListener)
    }
  }, []).                                           const onClick = useCallback(() => node.setExpanded(!node.expanded), [node]